# Подскажите API для практики

Tags: python, api, requests

Не давно начал изучать requests. Документацию прочитал, хочу закрепить практикой. Посоветуйте API какого сайта можно для этого использовать. Перефразирую: Какой API можно использовать для практики. Желательно бесплатный.

Comment: На выбор: VK APP, Telegram API, Facebook API и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот отличный сервис для обучения [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) можно сразу и в REST API разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

В докстринге самого модуля requests, а также в документации [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), есть примеры запросов на [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/#/). Это, пожалуй, наиболее популярный сервис для таких целей. Можно делать запросы и с разными вариантами Auth, и с разными форматами тела запроса и т.д.